# Stored Procedure - To update all columns of table with a single value '1' in a single query

Tags: php, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table with almost 40 fields in it. I want to update all these fields with a single value i.e 1 in a single query and i dont want to specify each column in the update query.

Can anyone help me in it??

Comment: which DB ? what have you tried ? help us help you...

Comment: I have InnoDB..i dint tried.. I dont have any idea if it can be done or not..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable";
$fields = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
```

Should help u retrieve the column names from the table, and store them in an array.

```
 $field_string = implode("='1', ", $fields);
```

changes the array to a string and adds `"=1"` to it. Then you can run this your query thus:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE sometable SET {$field_string}";
```

Comment: yes.. thannx.. it was helpful.. i did somewhre similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [*MySql UPDATE spec*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) it doesn't look like you can do it without detailing which columns you want to update.